Using Windows 11, how do I specify a single folder to be backed up?
Under Windows 10, I am able to specify which folder(s) are to be backed up to an NAS on my home network.  I access this ability via Settings > Files backup > Back up using File History > More Options > Back up these folders.  Here's a screenshot where I am backing up only the folder (recursively) C:\AAA.  Note the "Add a folder" option:
Windows 10 Settings:

With Windows 11, there is no back up section within Settings. However, there is the "Windows Backup" app, but it only allows me to back up to OneDrive (I need to back up to my NAS).  Finally, I tried Control Panel > System and Security > Save backup copies of your files with File History.  However, I don't see the ability to "Add a folder".  Oddly, there is "Exclude folders":
Windows 11 Control Panel:

An internet search did not provide any useful information.
Question:  Using Windows 11, how do I specify a single folder, such as C:\AAA, to be automatically, regularly-scheduled, backed up on a home network NAS?

In one screenshot you are looking within Settings in the other you are looking at Control Panel. Those are not equivalent.

@Ramhound thanks, you are correct.  OP has been updated.

Your screenshots didn’t change. Windows Backup != Shadow Copy (File History). There actually is a Windows Backup application on both Windows 10 and Windows 11 on both versions it’s found in Control Panel

@Ramhound  Thanks for sticking with me!  The Windows 10 screenshot shows how I was able to back up via Settings.  The Windows 11 screenshot does not show a similar Settings view because I have not found a back up section within Windows 11 Settings.  The Windows 11 screenshot shows that - out of desperation - I tried and failed via Control Panel.  In summary, I have not found a way to automatically back up a single folder to a local NAS within Windows 11.  I would be indebted if you could help me find a Windows 11 methodology that would accomplish that!

Not a direct answer but a solution I use myself : I created a batch file to zip a number of folders (Using 7zip command line utility). The batch then copies the zip to my NAS with a simple file copy command. Then I schedule every night execution of that batch file using task scheduler. In the batch I also use a SMTP blaster to send me an email to report success or failure.
